# AJAX call to re-render partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I know there are already tons of questions answered on this, but I am doing everything they are saying in those posts and it's still not working.

One thing to note is that it WAS working at one point, but now is no longer working.  I could've swore I didn't change anything, but perhaps I did.

I have a page with a bunch of partials on it (sorry, everything is in haml):

```
%h4 Query Editor

.row-fluid
    .span9
        = render 'query_editor'

    .span3
        = render 'documentation'

= image_tag "spinnerLarge.gif", size: "20x20", class: 'loading-indicator'
%span{ id: "results" }
    = render 'results'
```

What I'm looking to do is re-render the results partial.

The form is only in one of them (in haml):

```
= form_tag 'query', remote: true, class: "form-horizontal" do 

  = text_area_tag :query_editor, @current_connector.editor_state, rows: 10, class: 'input-block-level' 
  = text_area_tag :selected_query, nil, style: 'display:none'
```

Now I have some javascript where if you press Cmd+Enter, it runs the query in the text_area:

```
$(document).ready ->

  $('#query_editor').keydown (event) -> 
    if ((event.which == 115 && event.ctrlKey) || (event.which == 13 && event.metaKey)) 
      $('#selected_query').val($('#query_editor').getSelectedText())
      $('#results').prepend('Getting results...')      
      $(this).parent('form').submit()
      event.preventDefault()
```

In my controller, I have my code to execute the query (which I know works fine b/c I see the results come back when refreshing the page), but the results partial is not refreshed automatically.

query_tool_controller.rb:

```
def query

    # run the query and get some results and store in @results variable

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render action: 'view' }
      format.js { render layout: false }
      format.json { render json: @results, status: :success }
    end

  end
```

Here's my query.js.erb

`$('#results').html("<%= j render(partial: 'results').html_safe %>");`

I'm using rails 3.2.13 and I have the `javascript_include_tag "application"` included. I also have the following lines in my application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Any ideas?

---

I've also tried replacing my query.js.erb with the following:
`alert("hello, world");`

The alert is not popping up so it is not calling my query.js.erb file.  I guess the question is what am I doing wrong that is causing it not to run?

Comment: Does the request hit the server when you hit command-enter?  Any errors in the console?

Comment: Since you have remote:true in your form it will try to render the js templete just user format.js insted of format.html { render action: 'view' } and format.js { render layout: false } and then see if you are getting a 500 error in browser console.

Comment: @steakchaser, yes, the request does hit the server.  No errors I can see.  I see some warnings from pow.cx, but I don't think that's it since the version hasn't changed since when it was working.

Comment: @deep, I replaced the respond_to block with just `format.js` and the partial still doesn't re-render.  I've also tried just sending an alert, and that's still not working.  I've updated the question with that information.

Comment: ugh - stupid mistake that was NOT related to the ajax.  I was getting an error in the query method in my query_tool_connector class.  Pow.cx wasn't showing the error in their log files as it was part of the Rails logger output, so I had to check the development.log to find the error.  Since the issue is resolved, but not related to ajax, what should I do with this?  delete the question?